# VBScript: Get MAC address (ONLY) of specified IP Address

Tags: vbscript

I need to write a small script I can use to get **only** the MAC address of a specific IP address. So, you can use something like

```
arp -a 192.168.x.x | FIND "192.168.x.x"
```

But your result will still look something like:

```
Interface: 192.168.x.x --- 0x10
   192.168.x.x             00-00-00-00-00-00     dynamic
```

Somehow, using REGEX or other advanced parsing methods, I'd like to whittle that down to echo "00-00-00-00-00-00". I could use the following, but I'd like something cleaner:

```
set obj_exec = obj_shell.Exec("%comspec% /C arp -a 192.168.x.x | FIND "192.168.x.x" > c:\temp\tmp_gatewayMAC.txt")
set obj_FSO = createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set obj_file = obj_FSO.opentextfile("c:\temp\tmp_gatewayMAC.txt", 1)
do until obj_file.AtEndOfStream
    str_line = obj_file.readline
    if instr(str_line, "dynamic") > 0 then
        str_MACaddress = str_line
    end if
loop

str_MACaddress = replace(str_MACaddress, "dynamic","")
str_MACaddress = replace(str_MACaddress, "192.168.x.x","")
str_MACaddress = replace(str_MACaddress, " ","")
str_MACaddress = trim(str_MACaddress)
vbscript.echo(str_MACaddress)
```

For the time being, ignore how we determine the gateway IP address, as I'll come up with a method separate from this for that. Ideally, there's some other utility I can run (but can't find) like ARP but that just returns the MAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim IP
    IP = "192.168.1.1"

Dim getMACCommand
    getMACCommand = """%comspec%"" /q /c ""for /f ""skip=3 tokens=2"" %a in ('arp -a "& IP &"') do echo %a"""

Dim strMACAddress    
    strMACAddress = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec(getMACCommand).StdOut.ReadAll

    WScript.Echo strMACAddress
```

Yes, it can be done with a regexp, but since the data is retrieved from a spawned `cmd` instance, let it do the work

Comment: That's fantastic! Thank you. Unfortunately, I have absolutely no idea how the command itself works (this part: `for /f ""skip=3 tokens=2"" %a in`)

Comment: @Beems, it means: execute the `arp` command, from its output, skip three lines, for the remaining lines, using spaces as delimiters (by default) get the second token in the line and echo this token

Answer (score 0):

A little more code than the simple parser but this uses WMI to find the mac address of a network adapter with a specific IP address. Since it uses WMI the ip address will be stored in an array and we need to check if the ip is in the list for that particular adapter.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objWMIService, colItems, objItem
Dim strQuery, strIP, strMAC, strIPAddressToLocate

strIPAddressToLocate = "169.244.119.133"
strMAC = ""

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration"
Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://./root/CIMV2" )
Set colItems      = objWMIService.ExecQuery( strQuery, "WQL", 48 )

For Each objItem in colItems
    ' Ensure this adapter has at least one IP by checking if the value is an array. Filter out null/empty
    If IsArray( objItem.IPAddress ) Then
        If UBound( objItem.IPAddress ) = 0 Then
            ' Only one ip. Return that.
            strIP = objItem.IPAddress(0)
        Else
            ' Multiple IP's. Concat them so we can check contents with instr.
            strIP = Join( objItem.IPAddress, "," )
        End If

        If InStr(strIP,strIPAddressToLocate) <> 0 Then
            ' Get the mac address of the adapter matching this ip address. 
            strMAC = objItem.MacAddress
            ' Found the MAC we are looking for. Stop checking the loop
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next

If strMAC <> "" Then
    MsgBox "The IP Address: " & strIPAddressToLocate & " appears to be assigned to the adapter with the MAC Address: " & strMAC
Else
    MsgBox "Unable to locate a network adapater with the Ip Address: " & strIPAddressToLocate
End If
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work against remote addresses.

Comment: Sorry bout that. I didn't think you were looking for remote addresses